# What is the song playing during Midorya and Bakugo's fight?

Tags: my-hero-academia

What is the song playing when Midorya and Bakugo are fighting. The instant Midorya punches Bakugo's face really hard near the end of their fight.

It's season 3 episode 61. Where Midorya punches bakugo in the face but bakugo grabs his arm and propels them to the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its name is United States of Smash, although the one used in Bakugo and Midoriya's fight is just a small part of the complete original track.

[Link](https://youtu.be/Wl7pKRwcuso?t=30)